# Node async/await with promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

In a simple JS program, I need to have asyncOperation2 and asyncOperation3 execute sequentially along with asyncOperation1. Meaning I need the following to happen:

```
1) order of execution as  1,2,3 or 2,3,1
2) then after step 1. I need to preform an operation on the result of 1,2,3
```

Here's what I have so far(this will run in Node). But I cannot get the order of operations to happen as I described above.

```
const App = {
    total: 0,

    init: function () {
        // I want to run all 3 operations. (with 2 and 3 happening sequentially)
        Promise.all([App.asyncOperation1(1000), App.combine2and3()])
            .then((total) => {
                // then I want to use the result of all 3 operations
                console.log(`total from top: ${total}`);
            })
    },

    asyncOperation1: function (time) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var intervalID = setTimeout(function () {
                resolve(time);
            }, time);
        });
    },

    asyncOperation2: async function (time) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            return time;
        }, time);
    },

    asyncOperation3: async function (time) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            return time;
        }, time);
    },

    combine2and3: async function () {
        var value2 = await App.asyncOperation2(2000);
        var value3 = await App.asyncOperation3(1000);
        console.log(`value2: ${value2}`)
        console.log(`value3: ${value3}`)
        console.log(`summed total ${value2 + value3}`);
        return value2 + value3;
    },
};

App.init();
```

Actual results:

```
value2: undefined
value3: undefined
summed total NaN
total from top: 1000,NaN
```

Desired results:

```
value2: 2000
value3: 1000
summed total 3000
total from top: 1000,3000
```

Comment: `combine2and3` this should return a promise!

Comment: You can't return from inside `setTimeout` like that just because you marked the function `async`. Wrap it in a promise like you did in the first one that you don't call.

Comment: @RaajNadar - `combine2and3()` already does return a promise because it's declared `async`.  The issue is in `asyncOperation2()` and `asyncOperation3()`.  They return a promise that resolves to `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `asyncOperation2()` and `asyncOperation3()` return a promise 
(because of their `async` declaration) that has no resolved value (thus it's `undefined`) because those functions don't have their own return value.

```
asyncOperation2: async function (time) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        return time;     // this just returns back into the timer sub-system
    }, time);
    // there is no return value for your function here
    // thus the promise the async function returns has an undefined resolved value
},
```

Returning from inside the `setTimeout()` isn't the function's return value.  That's just a return back into the timer innards that happens long after the function itself has returned.  Remember, `setTimeout()` is non-blocking.  It schedules some code to run sometime in the future and then returns immediately and your function then finishes and returns (before `setTimeout()` has fired).  So, then sometime later, your `setTimeout()` fires and you return a value from that callback and that value just goes back into the timer sub-system, not to any of your code or to any promise.

Change those two functions to this:

```
function delay(t, v) {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v));
   }, t);
}

asyncOperation2: function (time) {
    return delay(time, time);
},

asyncOperation3: function (time) {
    return delay(time, time);
},
```

Now you have functions that return a promise that is resolved with the desired value.  Note, there's no need for them to be declared `async` either since you aren't using `await` inside the functions and you're already creating your own promise to return.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Very helpful

Answer (score 2):

`asyncOperation2` and `asyncOperation3` should resolve a promise if you want to some value to be returned. (what you're doing in `combine2and2`).

ps. returning some value from `setTimeout` would be wrong. You can't do that

Wrap them in a `Promise` and resolve the value you want to return from it.

Something like

```js
const App = {
    total: 0,

    init: function () {
        // I want to run all 3 operations. (with 2 and 3 happening sequentially)
        Promise.all([App.asyncOperation1(1000), App.combine2and3()])
            .then((total) => {
                // then I want to use the result of all 3 operations
                console.log(`total from top: ${total}`);
            })
    },

    asyncOperation1: function (time) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var intervalID = setTimeout(function () {
                resolve(time);
            }, time);
        });
    },

    asyncOperation2:  function (time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(time);
        }, time);
        });
    },

    asyncOperation3:  function (time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(time);
        }, time);
        })
    },

    combine2and3: async function () {
        var value2 = await App.asyncOperation2(2000);
        var value3 = await App.asyncOperation3(1000);
        console.log(`value2: ${value2}`)
        console.log(`value3: ${value3}`)
        console.log(`summed total ${value2 + value3}`);
        return value2 + value3;
    },
};

App.init();
```

Comment: Yeah that gives me what I want, Thanks! But I am a little confused. My understanding was: async and promises are the same thing under the hood, and that adding async to a function basically wraps the return value in a promise. If my understanding is correct, isn't the code you preposed redundant?

Comment: @Test1Test2 Glad to know that :) Consider accepting the answer. ps jfriend00's answer is really good. Read that to build more understandings

Comment: Your first sentence is very misleading.  Because `asyncOperation2` and `asyncOperation3` are declared `async`, they ALREADY return a  promise.  The issue is that the promise has no resolved value, therefore it's `undefined`.

Comment: Plus there's no reason in your code for `asyncOperation2` and `asyncOperation3` to be declared `async`.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for pointing that out. Yes. they have no reason to be declared `async`. I'll update it. Didn't notice that. just copied from OP's snippet.

Answer (score 0):

When you `return time` in the callback function passed to `setTimeout`, you only return in the callback function, not in the outer function. You have to wrap the `setTimeout` call in a promise, like in `asyncOperation1`. You can also make a helper function to avoid repetition.

```js
const wait = time => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(time), time)
);

const App = {
    total: 0,

    init: function () {
        // I want to run all 3 operations. (with 2 and 3 happening sequentially)
        Promise.all([App.asyncOperation1(1000), App.combine2and3()])
            .then((total) => {
                // then I want to use the result of all 3 operations
                console.log(`total from top: ${total}`);
            })
    },

    asyncOperation1: wait,

    asyncOperation2: wait,

    asyncOperation3: wait,

    combine2and3: async function () {
        var value2 = await App.asyncOperation2(2000);
        var value3 = await App.asyncOperation3(1000);
        console.log(`value2: ${value2}`)
        console.log(`value3: ${value3}`)
        console.log(`summed total ${value2 + value3}`);
        return value2 + value3;
    },
};

App.init();
```